# Getting the contextPath into external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

How to access `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` of jsp into a **external** javascript file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before the script in which you'll need it, you should be able to include something like this. then access it by variable name.

```
<script>var myContextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"</script>
<script src='theScriptINeedContextFor.js'></script>
```

Comment: it work but when i try to make a test in another js file `var prefix = "" ;
 if( contextPath != undefined )
  prefix = contextPath + "/" ;` i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: contextPath is not defined`

Comment: is this test.js included before or after the contextPath variable is declared? also, you want to check like this `if (typeof contextPath !== 'undefined') prefix = contextPath + "/";`

Comment: no i try it in a other jsp so the contextPath variable is not defined because i don't need it in this jsp page.

Comment: but it seems that `if (typeof contextPath !== 'undefined')` works.

Comment: no it's fine now it seems that `if (typeof contextPath !== 'undefined')` catch the exception.